# How to place the Google map Zoom Controller to the Top Right position

Tags: visualforce, javascript, google-map

I have created a Google Map VF page, using apex:map tag. In the Map, I need to place the Zoom control to the Top Right position(currently its in Top Left position) due to some visibility issue. Is there any way to implement this without using the JS code, since My Google map is based on apex:map tag. In case, if there is way to implement this,without changing to JS, it would have been very appreciated.

My code for the map as follows.

```
 <apex:map width="100%" height="910px" zoomLevel="6">
 <apex:repeat value="{!lstAccount}" var="con">
 <apex:mapMarker title="{!con.Name}" position="{latitude:{!con.PersonMailingLatitude},longitude:{!con.PersonMailingLongitude}}">
  <apex:mapInfoWindow >
  <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="font-weight: bold;">
  <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!con.Name}"/>
  </apex:outputPanel>
 <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!con.PersonMailingStreet}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel layout="block">
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!con.PersonMailingCity},{!con.PersonMailingState}"/>
```

My screenshot is as follows.[image]

Thanks Much In Advance 
Reshmi

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049029/move-zoom-bar-to-the-right-with-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: Hi, But to implement this, I guess we need to implement the corresponding JS  Google Map code. Pls let me know your thought.

Comment: Don't think you can do it without a Javascript. Don't see any issues with little javascript on a VF page.